# Pivot Table deleting field values when pivoting table on single field in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4

I have a polygon shapefile (multipart) that I would like to pivot on a single field using ArcMap 10.4.

Everything works well but the final table miss the values of the pivoted field (that are important as well as others).

Can anyone explain me why it happens and how to solve it?

[image: polygon shapefile with records]
[image: resulting pivot table]
[image: routine settings]

I checked "GRIDCODE" and "CODE" with "CODE" as pivot

[image: settings]
[image]

Checking "CODE" as Input and "GRIDCODE" as Pivot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What happens if you add CODE as well as GRIDCODE in your pivot?

Comment: I obtain a table that I can't use for my purpose and the problem of the CODE still persist.
I could not add an image here but basically I obtain a table where there is a field "GRIDCODE" populated by zeros and field called with the "CODE" but populated in a strange way.

Comment: basically, it group the field "GRIDCODE" maintaning repeated values and put the values in the field "FID", then has created as many field as the values in "CODE" and named by it and it populated these fields with the "POLY_AREA" values but associating each value to the own proper "FID" and "CODE"

Comment: Haven't used this tool yet, so digging into docs. Have you tried using summarize?

Comment: What is your expected output? Is it correct to say you want column with code, separate columns for gridcode1000, gridcode3000, etc. With area as values in these columns, as displayed above?

Comment: I have not use summarize before, but looking at it, it seems not useful to my purpose. I just want to transform the values of "GRIDCODE" in fields and then have "CODE" values as a unique values, I don't want perform math operation on the data

Comment: And to confirm, when you have checked code and gridcide  as inputs, with code as pivot, the table isn't usable? Could you post that example output?

Comment: The expected output basically is correct, the problem is that the field "CODE" is missing and thus I don't know to which element each row correspond

Comment: Just to be more clearer, the expected output is correct as that obtained chacking "GRIDCODE" as input field, "CODE" as pivot field and "POLY_AREA" as value field as posted in picture 2, the problem is that the field "CODE" that is the link to each original polygon is missed and thus I cannot join each record to the original feature

Comment: If I'm reading the examples in help correctly, your INPUT value needs to be CODE (a, b, c, etc.) and your PIVOT value needs to be GRIDCODE (900, 1000, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image below (help for the tool), use your field "CODE" as the input, and "GRIDCODE" as the pivot. The output example more closely matches what you wanted as your output.

[image]

Comment: you are right, the result perfectly match with what I expected to have, like using the field "GRIDCODE" as input and "CODE" as the pivot, but the problem still persist, even with your proposed solution the field "CODE" results empty in the final table.